# C++ - Difference between pointer of a class and object of class in initialization

Tags: c++, class

In C++ 
Suppose I have

```
class Sample{
 public:
 void someFunction();
};
```

In main() is there any difference between doing

```
Sample obj;
obj.someFunction();

AND

Sample *obj = new Sample();
obj->someFunction();
```

Is it only a matter of syntax or is there a performance/implementation difference? When should one be used over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple stuff - to do with heaps and stacks

```
Sample obj;
obj.someFunction();
```

obj is on the stack

AND

```
Sample *obj = new Sample();
obj->someFunction();
```

Is on the heap.

This needs to be deleted. It also lives outside scope.

The performance is about the same

Comment: Processor cache - Optimisation is easier for stuff on the stack

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more or point me to somewhere I can read up on processor cache optimized for stack variables? I wasn't aware there was a performance difference.

Comment: I think the OS has better knowledge about the variables on stack (because they are compile time known) before a program is executed. This could open up possibilities of promoting stack variables to cache when program is executed

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/08/24/what-you-need-to-know-about-prefetching Also the compiler will know the location of stuff when the scope starts.

Comment: @PDizzle745 Besides cache considerations, dynamically allocating memory is expensive.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sample obj;
obj.someFunction();
```

In this case, it's static allocation.
The memory for obj is allocated in the main() function's stack area.

```
Sample *obj = new Sample();
obj->someFunction();
```

In the other case, you dynamically created the object using new operator.
It is allocated in the heap memory.
After it's use, you should free it using delete operator.

```
delete obj;
```

So there is no other difference other than this. In case of dynamic allocation we must allocate and deallocate the memory as needed.
But in static allocation, it allocation happens on declaration and deallocation happens when the variable's scope is over.

Comment: It is not a static object